# GREP to search for second column in a text file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I need to GREP second column (path name) from the text file. I have a text file which has a md5checksum  filepath size . Such as:

```
ce75d423203a62ed05fe53fe11f0ddcf kart/pan/mango.sh 451b
8e6777b67f1812a9d36c7095331b23e2 kart/hey/local 301376b
e0ddd11b23378510cad9b45e3af89d79 yo/cat/so 293188b
4e0bdbe9bbda41d76018219f3718cf6f asuo/hakl 25416b
```

the above is the text file, I used `grep -Eo '[/]' file.txt` but it prints only / , but i want the output like this:

```
kart/pan/mango.sh
kart/hey/local
yo/cat/so
asuo/hakl
```

Lastly I have to use GREP.

Comment: GNU grep, or POSIX grep?

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP says they *have to* use GREP

Comment: Sure, that's why it isn't an answer `:)`

Comment: `grep -o '\s[a-z/][a-z/]*\s' file | grep -o '[^ ]*'` or with ERE `grep -Eo '\s(\w|/)+\s' file | grep -o '[^ ]*'`

Comment: Or better ``grep -Eo '\s\S+\s' file | grep -o '\S*'`` (and above -- need to add `'.'` to the list to match the first one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live with spaces before and after, you can use:

```
grep -o "\s[[:alnum:]/]*\s"
```

If you need the spaces removed, you will need some zero-width look-ahead/look-behind which is only available with -P (perl regexes), if you have that you can use:

```
grep -Po "(?<=\s)[[:alnum:]/]+(?=\s)"
```

- `(?<=\s)` - look-behind to see if there is a space preceding the string, but not capture it
- `(?=\s)` - look-ahead to see if there is a space after the match, but not capture it
- `[:alnum:]` - match alpha numeric chars
- `[[:alnum:]/]` - match alphanumeric chars and `/`
- `+` - match one or more

However, grep is not the right tool for this, cut/sed/awk are way better

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

-d ' ' means your delimiter is the space
-f 2 meant you want to only print field number two

Comment: OP says they have to use GREP

Comment: True, seems like I’ve missed that

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` instead.

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: *Lastly I have to use GREP.*

Answer (score 0):

When you are allowed to combine `grep` with other tools and your input file only has slashes in the second field, you can use

```
tr " " "\n" < file.txt | grep '/'
```